# How to control brightness of tkinter app?

Tags: python, tkinter

I just wanted to know if there is a way to change brightness of tkinter app without affecting brightness of desktop.

Comment: `tk_setPalette( 'SystemButtonFace' )` applied to `Tk()` or `Toplevel` will restore a tkinter master window to default color scheme. `SystemButtonFace` is the name given for a color value equal to `#f0f0f0'. Small increments of this value will brighten entire master window.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demonstration of brightness color in `tkinter`.

`tk_set_Palette` will affect most tkinter widgets.
Oops, found a bug in my code so I've cleaned it up

```py
def find( obj ):
    '''return string of keys & values for any tkinter widget that has keys attribute'''
    name = f"{type(obj).__name__}:\n    "
    try:
        return name + "\n    ".join( [ f"{x} = '{obj.cget(x)}'" for x in obj.keys() ] )
    except:
        return f"'{obj}' has no keys attribute"

class brightness:

    def __init__( self ):
        self.master = tkinter.Tk()
        self.master.update_idletasks()
        self.color = 15790320 # #f0f0f0 = SystemButtonFace
        self.var = tkinter.IntVar( self.master, value = self.color )
        self.flexx( self.master )

        self.label = tkinter.LabelFrame(
            self.master, labelanchor = 'n', text = self.master['background'] )
        self.label.grid( row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew' )
        self.flexx( self.label, r=None )
        self.flexx( self.label, r=None , c=1 )

        self.down = tkinter.Button(
            self.label, text = 'Color down',
            command = self.control_down )
        self.down.grid( row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'nsew' )
        self.up = tkinter.Button(
            self.label, text = 'Color up',
            command = self.control_up)
        self.up.grid( row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'nsew' )

        self.scroll = tkinter.Scale(
            self.label, orient = 'horizontal',
            resolution = 65793, label = 'Brightness Control',
            from_ = 0, to = 16777215, variable = self.var,
            command = self.control )
        self.scroll.grid( row = 1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='ew' )

        self.master.geometry( '200x200' )
        self.master.minsize( 334, 113 )

    def flexx( self, o, r = 0, c = 0, rw = 1, cw = 1 ):
        '''flexx will control grid manager static|dymanic growth'''
        if r != None:
            o.rowconfigure( r, weight = rw )
        if c != None:
            o.columnconfigure( c, weight = cw )

    def convert( self ):
        col = '#' + ( '000000' + hex( self.color )[2:])[~5:]
        self.var.set( self.color )
        self.label['text'] = col
        self.master.tk_setPalette( col )

    def control_up( self ):
        self.color += 65793
        if self.color > 16777215:
            self.color = 15790320
        col = self.convert( )

    def control_down( self ):
        self.color -= 65793
        if self.color < 0: # 15790320:
            self.color = 16777215
        col = self.convert( )

    def control( self, n ):
        self.color = int( n )
        col = self.convert( )

if __name__ == '__main__':

    bright = brightness( )
    tkinter.mainloop()
```